# Stream monad operation bind used both as a map and filter operation?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, monads

I want to create a stream monad with the `return` and `bind` operations

I tried the following:

```
module type STREAM_MONAD_SIG =
  sig
    type 'a stream 
    val return : 'a -> 'a stream 
    val bind : 'a stream  -> ('a -> 'b stream ) -> 'b stream 
    val (>>=) : 'a stream  -> ('a -> 'b stream ) -> 'b stream 
    val div5 : 'a stream -> 'a stream
end
```

```
module StMonad : STREAM_MONAD_SIG  = struct 
  type 'a stream = Nil | Cons of 'a * ( unit -> 'a stream)
  let return v = Cons(v, fun() -> Nil)
  let rec bind v f =
    match v with 
    | Nil -> Nil
    | Cons(h, t) -> 
        match f h with
        | Nil -> bind (t()) f
        | Cons(r_h, _) -> Cons(r_h, fun () -> bind (t()) f)
  let (>>=) = bind
  let div5 s1 = s1 >>= fun x -> if x mod 5 == 0 then return x else Nil
  let add2 s1 = s1 >>= fun x -> return (x+2)
end
```

My question is: Can this bind function be used both as a map and filter operation based on the type of `f` we pass? Filter application like `div5`, and `add2` for map.

Example Input for `div5`:

```
open StMonad;;
let st = Cons(5, fun () -> Cons(6, fun () -> Cons(10, fun () -> Nil)));;
let res = div5 st;;
```

Output: `Cons(5, Cons(10, fun () -> Nil))`.

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: I tried, it works, but there was someone else said that I had 'enough problems` with the `bind` solution, and I can't get which problem.

Comment: yes, map and filter would work OK. but what if you wanted e.g. to duplicate each element in the stream, e.g. turning `1,2,3` to `1,1,2,2,3,3`? then you'd bind the input stream to `fun x -> (Cons x, fun() -> (Cons x, fun() -> Nil))`. would _that_ work?

Comment: That's an important remark, how would you solve that?

Comment: were you able to pinpoint the problematic place in your code? try following the execution, in your mind, with the function I provided. (please type @ and then user name, in your response, so I'll get notified)

Comment: @WillNess it is this piece `Cons(r_h, _) -> Cons(r_h, fun () -> bind (t()) f)`?

Comment: yes. you ignore there something, right? What is it, can you tell? should it really be ignored? you treat the stream as if it contains ... how many elements?

Comment: @WillNess as if it contains one element

Comment: Why did you delete your zipper question? It was a good question :-(

Comment: @Stef Sorry, I just solved it myself, I was just a bit confused initially.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, map and filter would work OK with your implementation.

But what if you wanted e.g. to duplicate each element in the stream, e.g. turning `1,2,3` to `1,1,2,2,3,3`? Then you'd want to bind the input stream to `fun x -> (Cons x, fun() -> (Cons x, fun() -> Nil))`. But that wouldn't work since your code ignores the tails of the streams produced for each element in the input stream:

```
....
    | Cons(h, t) -> 
        match f h with
        | Nil -> bind (t()) f
        | Cons(r_h, _) -> Cons(r_h, fun () -> bind (t()) f)
                (* ^^^ here *)
....
```

Your current code produces at most one element for each element in the input  stream:

```
 [    a     b    c   .....     n       ... ]     (* input   *)
      |     |    |             |
      f     f    f             f
      |     |    |             |
 [ [a1 a2]  []  [c1] .....  [n1 n2 n3] ... ]     (* outputs *)
---------------------------------------------
 [  a1           c1  .....   n1        ... ]     (* result  *)

(*  ^^ __________^^__________^^____________         map     *)
(*          ^^ ____________________________         filter  *)
```

Instead, all produced elements must be spliced-in, without exception:

```
 [ [a1 a2]  []  [c1] .....  [n1 n2 n3] ... ]     (* outputs *)
---------------------------------------------
 [  a1 a2        c1  .....   n1 n2 n3  ... ]     (* result  *)
```

In code:

```
....
  let rec bind v f =
    match v with 
    | Nil -> Nil
    | Cons(h, t) -> appendBind (f h) t f
  and appendBind s1 t f =
    match s1 with 
    | Nil -> bind (t()) f
    | Cons(h, t1) -> (Cons h, fun () -> appendBind (t1()) t f)
....
```